# Run PHP and HTML code from a string

Tags: php, html

I have a string stored in a variable in my php code, something like this:

```
<?php

$string = "

<?php $var = 'John'; ?>

<p>My name is <?php echo $var; ?></p>

";

?>
```

Then, when using the $string variable somewhere else, I want the code inside to be run properly as it should. The PHP code should run properly, also the HTML code should run properly. So, when echoing the $string, I will get `My name is John` wrapped in a `<p>` tag.

Comment: could you use a function and a heredoc?

Comment: You should probably just use an included file

Comment: You do _not_ want to do this. This typically opens _huge_ security holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do this. If you still insist, you should check [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) aka `evil` function. First thing to know, you must not pass opening `<?php` tag in string, second you need to use single quotes for php script You want to evaluate (variables in single quotes are not evaluated), so your script should look something like:

```
<?php

$string = '
<?php $var = "John"; ?>
<p>My name is <?php echo $var; ?></p>
';
// Replace first opening <?php in string
$string = preg_replace('/<\?php/', '', $string, 1); 
eval($string);
```

However, this is considered very high security risk.

Comment: You're right about security. My client insisted like crazy in a feature which can be done only this way. He knows he's responsible for everything as long as it works. Thanks, I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

So if I'm right, you have the $var = 'John'; stored in a different place.

Like this:

```
<?php $var = 'John'; ?>
```

And then on a different place, you want to create a variable named $String ?
I assume that you mean this, so I would suggest using the following:

```
<?php
    $String = "<p>My name is ".$var." </p>";
    echo $String;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define $var outside the $string variable, like this

```
<?php

$var="John";
$string = "<p>My name is $var</p>";

?>
```

Or you can use . to concatenate the string

```
 <?php

    $var="John";
    $string = "<p>My name is ".$var."</p>";

    ?>
```

Both codes will return the same string, so now when doing

```
<?php
    echo $string;
?>
```

You will get `<p>My name is John</p>`