# How to insert a php if statement inside of a string

Tags: php, html

I'm writing code for a little website I made and I'm trying to have it where inside the string it will run the 'if' statement and not just display it to the screen.

```
$posts .= "<div class='posts'><p>$output</p> if($showName == 1){echo: '<h4>Posted by: $name</h4>';} </div>";

echo: "$posts";
```

I want it to where if $showName equals '1' it will display 'Posted by: Dylan'. And if $showName equals '0' nothing inside of the 'if' statement will be displayed. Currently this is being displayed

```
if(1 == 1){echo: '
Posted by: Dylan
';}
```

Sorry if this is not good. This is my first post on here.
If you have any questions I'll respond as quickly as I can

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run PHP and HTML code from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125789/run-php-and-html-code-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ternary operator** and change code as follows

```
$showname = $shoeName == 1 ? '<h4>Posted by:'.$name.'</h4>': '';
$posts .= "<div class='posts'><p>$output</p>".$showname."</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

i gathered the response into a var called response then appended it to the string.

```
if($showName == 1){
$response =  '<h4>Posted by: '.$name.'</h4>';
}else{
$response = '';
}
$posts = "<div class='posts'><p>".$output."</p>".$response."</div>";
echo $posts;
```

Comment: you have to initialize **$response** with an empty value or will trigger an error